# ActionView Ruby Code Not Evaluating in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, actionview

I have the following Rails code in a HAML view:

```
= form_tag ..... do
  - @someArray.each do |age|
    = age
    = check_box_tag "ages[#{age}]", @keys.has_key? age ? checked : unchecked
```

What I'm trying to do here is check or uncheck this checkbox according to whether `age` variable is in the instance variable in the controller `@keys`. This however, throws a `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tASSOC` error.

Any ideas why this Ruby code isn't evaluating? It's after a `=` in HAML which is precisely what is needed to evaluate Ruby code. Am I wrong? Sorry I'm new to Rails and things are pretty confusing in the beginning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`checked` and `unchecked` are variables here; I suppose you wanted to write `"checked"` and `"unchecked"`.

Also, there might be a problem with the precedence: `@a.b? c ? d : e` is evaluated as `@a.b?(c ? d : e)`, and not as `(@a.b?(c)) ? d : e` as you probably wish.

Comment: In Haml (or Rails templates in general), do Ruby variables always go between quotations even if the ruby code is code `=`? Also, I wrapped checked and unchecked with quotations, and its still not working. I also added the brackets to fix precedence.

Comment: Here's what I have:
`= check_box_tag "ages[#{age}]", :id => "#{age}", (@keys.has_key?(age)) ? "checked" : "unchecked"`

Comment: Variables don't go into quotes; as in Ruby, `"#{age}"` is equivalent to `age.to_s`. However, `checked` is not a variable that you have defined - it should be a string. If you're still having an error, I can't see where it is :( Also, just one pair of brackets is already sufficient to fix the precedence; even though putting both pairs is not at all an error.

Comment: :-/ I can't figure it out at all.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing precedence `@keys.has_key?(age)` you have to take care of arguments **order** in `check_box_tag` method. See [Documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag):

`check_box_tag(name, value = "1", checked = false, options = {})`

So try:

```
= check_box_tag age, age, @keys.has_key?(age) ? true : false
```